# Question about combined ac/DC signals

Tags: ac, dc, bias

Would anyone care to provide a simple explanation about the interaction between an audio signal and a DC bias current in regards to voltage/current calculations? For instance, an audio signal with 1v peak to peak interacts with a transistor base voltage divider at 3v. I am new to audio signal calculations. Does the positive waveform voltage (and current I assume) add to the DC bias and negative waveform subtract? Forgive me if I'm completely wrong. Trying to get a mental model before I delve into complex equations. Thanks for any help.

Comment: that is correct The DC provides a fixed bias and the AC modulates the base current to a lesser extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltages simply add.  To find the currents, consider any of the possible instantaneous voltages.

For example, let's say you have a 1 V peak audio signal with 3 V DC bias.  That means that the actual voltage can be anywhere from 2 V to 4 V.  To see what your circuit does with that, consider each of the voltages in the range separately.

At the least, consider what happens at the limiting conditions of 2 V and 4 V.  For audio, you want to ensure that the subsequent circuit doesn't clip to either rail, or become non-linear for some other reason.  If the circuit behaves proportionally (to the AC component), then you don't have to analyze all the in-between states.

Comment: That was a great example and really helped a lot to move forward. Appreciated Olin.